# Object created even the if statement is not satisfied in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I have only one object in my environment :

```
> y
Error: object 'y' not found
> x
[1]  4 NA NA
```

When I run the following if statement (if returns FALSE, so I assumed the statement inside if is not run)

```
if (length(x[!is.na(x)]>1)){
    y=rep(NA,length(x[!is.na(x)])-1);
    for (i in 1:length(y)){
        y[i]=x[!is.na(x)][i+1]-x[!is.na(x)][i]
    }}
```

x remains the same but y is created

```
> y
[1] NA
```

I expected no object named y is found.
Why is it? Is there a way I make the if statement not run?

Comment: Try with `if (sum(!is.na(x))>1)`. Or `if (length(x[!is.na(x)])>1)` with the brace in the right place. (;

Comment: Your right bracket of `length()` is misplaced: it should be `length(x[!is.na(x)])>1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first if statement is satisfied. This `x[!is.na(x)]>1` already evaluates to `TRUE`, but you look at the length of this expression. Since in R even an object with one element is a  vector, this also has length 1. `if(1)` here 1 is considered as `TRUE` so the expression after `if` will run as well, which creates `y`.

Comment: You are right. It should have been length(x[!is.na(x)])>1. y is no longer created.